# REST API Get and Post When should pick proper one

Tags: rest, api

I am using ASP.NET CORE and currently studying REST APIs. So, I know the different between different verbs, but I cannot explain one thing to myself.
If we have a URL - /customers/{id} and we are using it to GET and POST a customer. How could it tell whether to read or create a new customer?

In the controller, I could have that:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Customer(string id)
        {
            // not important
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Customer(string id)
        {
            // not important
        }
```

So, I want to create a new customer and use /customers/{John}.
How would it pick the HttpPost, instead of HttpGet, If they both have the same parameteres?

Comment: This is determined by your frontend, or whatever calls you API. Whether you're using curl, fetch, axios, httpie, your browser, or anything else that utilizes the http protocol to read or write, it needs to specify which http verb is being used. How do you call your API?

Comment: This is just a scenario, lets say I am calling this /customers/{id} through html page where I have input for the {id}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified by the consumer of the API. Since you said you're calling it from a webpage illustrate with an example using the javascript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API.

POST example:

```
fetch("/customers/' + custId, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify(data), //data being your customer data
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

GET example:

```
fetch("/customers/' + custId) //if not specified, fetch defaults to GET
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Comment: Alright, I understand that, thanks. However, where do I specify that the request must be a POST, if I am the client and I click on a button 'Create Customer', this button should be wired to the POST request, how does that happen? If I have the same parameters as the GET request, how does the server know, which http verb should it use?

Comment: You wrap each of these request in a function: `getCustomer(id)`, and `createCustomer(data)`. You then map your _Create customer_ button to the latter function (e.g. `onClick` or `onSubmit`). By doing this, clicking on _Create customer_ will send a POST request to the server side. On the server side, this request will then be handled by the function already annoted with `[HttpPost]`. That's what this annotation means; it will only handle POST request.

Comment: Done, may I ask, how do we achive that in ASP.NET? I believe, I do that through a form, just like     <form  method="post"> // text </form>, specifying the method request to be POST?

Comment: Sure, you could use a form. I don't know ASP.NET, but I assume this solution wouldn't be specific to that framework. You use regular html and JavaScript on the front side right? Then yes, you can use regular form submit with method="post"

Comment: Cheers mate! You were very helpful!